# google ads enableLazyLoad causes endless loop on safari and IE

Tags: javascript, angular, ads, google-dfp

I have a page with a list and three ads interspersed throughout the list.  I have enabled lazy load like so :

```
pubads.enableLazyLoad({
  fetchMarginPercent: 200,  
  renderMarginPercent: 100,  
  mobileScaling: 1.0 
});
```

This works fine on chrome, firefox and edge.  However on safari and IE it causes an endless loop which freezes the page.  I'm not sure how this enableLazyLoad works but I'd imagine theres a scroll watcher involved.  Do browsers handle scroll watching differently?  Would it make sense do browser sniff and deactivate enable lazy load for safari and IE?